# Warning: imagecolorallocate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, file, upload, prestashop

When a customer tries to upload an jpg image in prestashop using my frontoffice product page I get this error:

```
Warning: imagecolorallocate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/peciatky/eshop/images.inc.php on line 255 
Warning: imagefilledrectangle() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/peciatky/eshop/images.inc.php on line 256 
Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/peciatky/eshop/images.inc.php on line 259 
Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/peciatky/eshop/images.inc.php on line 336 
Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/peciatky/eshop/images.inc.php on line 339
```

The file source can be found here: http://pastebin.ca/2497875

Honestly, I have been at this the whole night and could not find the solution to why this bugger is behaving this way. It's really annoying as I have a shop live and people not being able to upload images to orders is really bad :/

If you want to test the frontend here's the link to the store page that does not work, just try attaching a jpg or png file and click Ulozit (save)
http://www.peciatky.sk/samonamacacie/11-printy-4910.html

Comment: You probably get an error when trying to create the resource as e.g. [`imagecreatetruecolor`](http://us1.php.net/imagecreatetruecolor) "Returns (...) FALSE on errors." boolean == FALSE != resource ;)

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. Now I just need to figure out why it returns FALSE :/ I tried enabling loglevel high on apache2 but the log did not give anything usable - is there a way to test the problem step by step on a live server?

Comment: For starters, do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?

Comment: Yes, and there are no new errors returned in `tail var/log/apache2/error.log`.
I've added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the second line of the .php file right after `<?php`

Comment: When I change the function in [images.inc.php](http://pastebin.ca/2497875) on line 255 to `$destImage = imagecreatetruecolor(10,10);` it runs through without errors, but nothing is saved to the backend - I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by installing [Attribute Wizard pro](http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/attribute-modules/34-attribute-wizard-pro.html), a prestashop module that can do file uploads and that does not use the problematic .php file.

I had to buy the module but it was faster and probably cheaper than to spend my time on debugging with no guarantee of a solution in sight.